# How to accept location permissions for BluetoothLE with AndroidThings?

Tags: bluetooth, android-things

I am using preview 3 of the androidthings SDK with a Bluetooth LE device.

In order to enable Bluetooth I had to call the following, to bypass requesting the permission from the user:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.enable()
```

However I then got a SecurityException when scanning:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results

Using Vysor, I got around this by requesting the permissions and accepting the permission with the following request:

```
requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

Is there a way to accept the permission without requiring the use of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Android Things [platform overview docs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#behavior_changes):

> Requesting Permissions at Runtime is not supported because embedded devices aren't guaranteed to have a UI to accept the runtime dialog. Declare permissions that you need in your app's manifest file. All normal and dangerous permissions declared in your app's manifest are granted at install time.

The reason you are seeing the `SecurityException` is due to the following known issue listed on the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html):

> Dangerous permissions requested by apps are not granted until the next device reboot.

Rebooting the device after the app is installed will grant the new permissions in your app manifest. Another method you can use during development is to install directly over ADB with the `-g` flag:

```
$ adb install -g <APK File>
```

This will grant the dangerous permissions at install-time.